# Why 'name' is not passed to React component?

Tags: reactjs

Is 'name' parameter unique in any way, why it is not passed?

I have a componenet called `Input`. This is the interface for it:

```js
interface Props {
    className?: string
    colour?: ThemeColour
    multiLine?: boolean
    keyPath?: (string | number)[]
    onChangePrio?: Function
    onBlurPrio?: Function
    valuePrio?: any
    isInt?: Boolean
    isFloat?: Boolean
    formState?: any
    setFormState?: Function
    name?: string
}
const Input = ({
    className = '',
    multiLine = false,
    keyPath,
    onChangePrio,
    onBlurPrio,
    valuePrio,
    isInt,
    isFloat,
    formState,
    setFormState,
    name,
    ...rest
}: Props) => {
    console.log('n1', name)
```

and here it is called:

```js
<InputGroup title="Egyéb információ">
<Input
    formState={formState}
    setFormState={setFormState}
    name="additionalInfo"
    placeholder="pl. Szállással"
/>
</InputGroup>
```

Is it a problem if optional parameters as not set as undefined or null?

I see only these repeating lines:

```js
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
n1 undefined
```

Why, though `name` is passed at least in one case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, of course it isn't a problem. Any props you haven't defined when using the component will just be `undefined` within the component (unless overridden by e.g. `defaultProps`).

```
function Greet({ name }: { name?: string }) {
  return <div>Hello, {String(name)}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greet name="János" />
      <Greet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

will render

```
Hello, János
Hello, undefined
```

Comment: Ok, but `name` is passed, why it is not received then?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal reproducible example where `name` isn't correctly passed?